# Byte arrays in java

Tags: java, hex, byte

Hey I need to store the following hex value in a byte array -  0xCAFEBABEDEADBEEF.

So I tried to store it like so.

```
byte[] v0 = {11001010,11111110,10111010,10111110,11011110,10101101,10111110,11101111};
```

where 11001010 is CA in binary, 11111110 is FE in binary etc.

But I get an error saying 11001010 is an int, so I presume this is because bytes are signed bytes in java, and we can only have values between +127 and -128.

So is there way I can do this in java(maybe using unsigned bytes...if they exist!?)
Thanks guys.

Comment: It depends on what version of Java you are using. For 1.7, you can prefix each binary value with "0b", otherwise you will have to use hex and prefix each hex value with "0x".

Answer (score 10):

Put `0b` in front of the number. You may also have to cast to `byte`:

```
byte[] v0 = {(byte)0b11001010,(byte)0b11111110,...};
```

The `0b` prefix means it is a binary number.

If you want it to be easier to read, you can use `0x` for hexadecimal:

```
byte[] v0 = {(byte)0xCA,(byte)0xFE,(byte)0xBA,(byte)0xBE,...};
```

Here's a way to do it (binary form) if you're using a Java version less than 7:

```
byte[] v0 = {Byte.parseByte("11001010", 2),...);
```

Comment: @user1974753 A small caveat in the JLS. The `0x` and `0b` literals are all interpreted and then sign-extended to `int` values. The casts to `byte` that Doorknob added will take only the last 8 bits from the sign-extended `int`, so this should work fine.

Answer (score 5):

The literal `11001010` represents a decimal of `int` type and of value `11,001,010` - that is 11 milions and something.

If you're using **Java 7**, you can define binary literals using the `0b` prefix, such as `0b11001010`. To improve readability, you can put underscores in the values, such as `0b_1100_1010`.

However, note that the type of even such binary (or hexadecimal) literal is still `int`. This, together with the fact that bytes are (unfortunately) **signed** in Java (thus their value is in range `-128 to 127`) results in the problem that a literal with a value larger than `127` has to be manually cast to `byte`:

```
// 0b_1001_0001 or 0x91 is 145 in decimal
byte b1 = (byte) 0b_1001_0001;
byte b2 = (byte) 0x91;
```

However, the value of such byte will be `-111` (145 - 256). To get back the unsigned value, you need to manually add the module (256) to the value:

```
int i1 = b1 + 256;
int i2 = b1 & 0xff;
// both i1 and i2 are 145
```

For more information see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516021/literal-syntax-for-byte-arrays-using-hex-notation)

Comment: But byte[] v0 = {0xCA}; gives me the following error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte ?????

Comment: @user1974753 Typecast it with byte like `(byte) 0xCA`.

Comment: But, 11001010 = 202 is decimal, CA in hex, so the max we can hold in a byte in java is +127, so is there any way I can store 11001010(202 in decimal)  in a byte?

Answer (score 3):

If write byte to byte, you can use:

```
byte[] v0 = {0b11001010, 0b11111110, 0b10111010, ... }
```

or

```
byte[] v0 = {0xCA, 0xFE, ... }
```

Comment: But byte[] v0 = {0xCA}; gives me the following error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte ?????